# Samba4 Active Directory, Dovecot/Postfix LDAP auth lookups

Tags: linux, dovecot, samba4

I have 2 Ubuntu linux 14.04 servers with Samba4 on them. One is the AD master, the other is the AD backup.

Before the Samba 3.8.4 update, my Postfix+Dovecot servers were able to do user lookups and authentication lookups. Now they cannot.

postfix says

```
warning: dict_ldap_connect: Unable to bind to server [redacted] (Strong(er) authentication required)
```

dovecot says

```
auth: Error: LDAP: ldap_start_tls_s() failed: Can't contact LDAP server
```

TLS is enabled on the Dovecot configuration. It seems to be an issue with the self-signed certificate in the Samba AD setup.

ldapserch ... -Z gives

```
ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
    additional info: (unknown error code)
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

openssl s_client -connect [ip and port of AD server] -showcerts actually hands me the cert as expected.

```
...
Server certificate
subject=/O=Samba Administration/OU=Samba - temporary autogenerated certificate/CN=DC-01.[redacted]
issuer=/O=Samba Administration/OU=Samba - temporary autogenerated certificate/CN=DC-01.[redacted]
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/O=Samba Administration/OU=Samba - temporary autogenerated certificate/CN=DC-01.[redacted]
/O=Samba Administration/OU=Samba - temporary autogenerated certificate/CN=DC-01.[redacted]
....
Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
....
```

Looking at : https://access.redhat.com/articles/2243351
I tried :

```
tls verify peer = no_check
ldap server require strong auth = no
```

**This successfully allows plain-text LDAP loookups on port 389.**
(edit from previous)

Ubuntu 14.04 cert parts are in :
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configuring_LDAP_over_SSL_%28LDAPS%29_on_a_Samba_AD_DC

I've tried importing the CA .pem file from the DC to the mail server, but it doesn't seem to correct dovecot or postfix'es TLS LDAP connection problems.

Comment: according to the documentation (https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configuring_LDAP_over_SSL_%28LDAPS%29_on_a_Samba_AD_DC) the ca is  /usr/local/samba/private/tls/ca.pem , so if you import that to the hosts where dovecot and postfix run, then it should work again. Another option (don't) is to disable tls in smb.conf

Comment: natxo asenjo, I copied the ca.pem and imported it to the openssl ca store on the mail server but it didn't seem to make it happy. does it need the whole chain in a pem?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17748/trust-a-self-signed-pem-certificate, see the answer by Thom Wiggers. I have no experience using with this on debian/ubuntu